# how to Laravel eloquent having array

Tags: laravel, eloquent

how to type this sql in laravel eloquent 10

```
$data = array:2 [
  0 => "3"
  1 => "5"
  2 => "1"
]
```

relations

```
public function followActionFollowStudent()
{
    return $this->hasMany(FollowActionFollowStudent::class, 'follow_student_id', id');

}
```

**i need sql as this below**

```
select `follow_students`.*, 
(select `user_id` 
from `follow_action_follow_student` 
where `follow_action_follow_student`.`follow_student_id` = `follow_students`.`id` order by `id` desc limit 1) as `last_user_action` 
from `follow_students`
 where exists (select * from 
`follow_action_follow_student` 
where `follow_students`.`id` = `follow_action_follow_student`.`follow_student_id`) and (exists (select *, (select `follow_action_id` 
from `follow_action_follow_student` 
where `follow_action_follow_student`.`follow_student_id` = `follow_students`.`id` and `user_id` = 6
 order by `id` desc limit 1) as `last_state` 
from `follow_action_follow_student` where `follow_students`.`id` = `follow_action_follow_student`.`follow_student_id` and `follow_action_id` in ('3', '5', '1') having `last_state` in ('3', '5', '1') )) having `last_user_action` = 6
```

i try this code

```
FollowStudent::withTrashed()->whereHas('followActionFollowStudent', function ($q) use ($data) {
                                $q->whereIn('follow_action_id', $data)
                                    ->addSelect(['last_state' => FollowActionFollowStudent::select('follow_action_id')
                                        ->whereColumn('follow_action_follow_student.follow_student_id', 'follow_students.id')
                                        ->when(! auth()->user()->hasRole('isAdmin'), fn ($q) => $q->where('user_id', auth()->id()))
                                        ->orderBy('id', 'DESC')
                                        ->limit(1),
                                    ])
                                    ->having('last_state', $data);
                            });
```

it return sql

```
select `follow_students`.*, (select `user_id` from `follow_action_follow_student` where `follow_action_follow_student`.`follow_student_id` = `follow_students`.`id` order by `id` desc limit 1) as `last_user_action` from `follow_students` where exists (select * from `follow_action_follow_student` where `follow_students`.`id` = `follow_action_follow_student`.`follow_student_id`) and (exists (select *, (select `follow_action_id` from `follow_action_follow_student` where `follow_action_follow_student`.`follow_student_id` = `follow_students`.`id` and `user_id` = 6 order by `id` desc limit 1) as `last_state` from `follow_action_follow_student` where `follow_students`.`id` = `follow_action_follow_student`.`follow_student_id` and `follow_action_id` in ('3', '5', '1') having `last_state` = '3')) having `last_user_action` = 6 limit 10 offset 0
```

The problem is Laravel returns

```
having `last_state` = '3'
```

i need return

```
 having `last_state` in ('3','5','1')
```

Answer (score 2):

**the work code after update**

i replace

```
->having('last_state', $data);
```

with

```
->havingRaw('last_state in ('.implode(',', $data).')');
```

so full code is

```
FollowStudent::withTrashed()->whereHas('followActionFollowStudent', function ($q) use ($data) {
                            $q->whereIn('follow_action_id', $data)
                                ->addSelect(['last_state' => FollowActionFollowStudent::select('follow_action_id')
                                    ->whereColumn('follow_action_follow_student.follow_student_id', 'follow_students.id')
                                    ->when(! auth()->user()->hasRole('isAdmin'), fn ($q) => $q->where('user_id', auth()->id()))
                                    ->orderBy('id', 'DESC')
                                    ->limit(1),
                                ])
                                ->havingRaw('last_state in ('.implode(',', $data).')')
                        });
```

Comment: Yep, I wasn't sure will Laravel convert PHP array to SQL on binding, sorry for this thing

Answer (score 0):

Replace `having('last_state', $data)` with `havingRaw('last_state IN (?)', [ implode(',', $data)])`

Comment: thank you for help
work for me                
->havingRaw('last_state in ('.implode(',', $data).')');

Comment: your code
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '?)) having `last_user_action` = ?) as `aggregate_table`' at line 1